# Can I run this code locally? Pytorch + matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I tried a PyTorch tutorial and they write this code in Google Colab.
Does someone know if I can run this code locally?
or convert it somehow...
Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch

weight = 0.7  # b in linear regression
bias = 0.3  # a in linear regression

start = 0
end = 1
step = 0.02
X = torch.arange(start, end, step).unsqueeze(dim=1)
y = weight * X + bias

train_split = int(0.8 * len(X))

X_train, y_train = X[:train_split], y[:train_split]
X_test, y_test = X[train_split:], y[train_split:]

def plot_predictions(train_data=X_train, train_labels=y_train,
                     test_data=X_test, test_labels=y_test,
                     predictions=None):
    # Plots training data, test data and compares predictions 
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

    # Plot training data in blue
    plt.scatter(train_data, train_labels, c="b", s=4, label="Training data")

    # Plot test data in green
    plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", s=4, lable="Testing data")

    # Are there predictions?
    if predictions is not None:
        # Plot the predictions if they exist
        plt.scatter(test_data, predictions, c="r", label="Predictions")

    # Show the legend
    plt.legend(prop={"size": 14})


plot_predictions()
```

I'm writing here things because it's giving me error to add some more information........
this is the real error -->

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/pytorch_2.py", line 85, in <module>
    plot_predictions()
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/pytorch_2.py", line 74, in plot_predictions
    plt.scatter(test_data, test_labels, c="g", s=4, lable="Testing data")
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2780, in scatter
    __ret = gca().scatter(
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1423, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4626, in scatter
    collection._internal_update(kwargs)
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1186, in _internal_update
    return self._update_props(
  File "/Users/michal/Desktop/coding/practice/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 1160, in _update_props
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: PathCollection.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lable'
```

Comment: What happens when you **try**?

Comment: I'm new here so it's a little hard to me to write here but I edited the post and the error is at the bottom

Comment: Did you not notice that you misspelled "label"?  That's what caused the error.

Comment: ohhh I forgot the 'e'... thank you for your time!!